# navpush not working in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to do some basic routing in Ionic 2.  Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import {FishPage} from '../fish';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  goFish: FishPage;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.goFish = FishPage;
  }

}
```

and here is FishPage:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'fish.html'
})
export class FishPage {

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

and here is the html:

```
<ion-content>
    <button ion-button full [navPush]="goFish" >Go Fish</button>
</ion-content>
```

However, when i click on the button I get the following error:

> EXCEPTION: Error in ./HomePage class HomePage - inline template:16:2
>   caused by: No component factory found for FishPage

Comment: Could you post your app.module file? May be something wrong with declaration in there.

Comment: Thanks, I actually just fixed this by adding FishPage to app.module.  I guess my question really is:  What does app.module do?  It's not in any of the ionic documentation.

Comment: Can you make sure that FishPage is included in the 'declarations' and 'entryComponents' on your app.modules.ts page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to make sure that your FishPage and all others are included in declarations and entryComponents in `app.module` file. The purpose of this file is just to declare/represent before hand all the components, providers, directives or pipes that the application uses. Afterwards the module is then loaded into app/main.dev.ts or app/main.prod.ts.

Since Ionic 2 leverages Angular 2, take a look at Angular 2's documentation instead.

- [Angular 2 architecture guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html)
- [Angular 2 ngModule guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html)

These guides go into detail of the changes in the building blocks for angular apps.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

Changes in regards to app/main.dev.ts and app/main.prod.ts that were mentioned in my original answer.

> 1. main.dev.ts and main.prod.ts have been deprecated in favor of main.ts with the content of main.dev.ts. The content of main.ts will
>      be optimized at build time for production builds.
> 2. Builds are now always development (non-AoT) by default. To enable prod builds, use the --prod option.

[Taken from Ionic 2 Chanelog](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)